# Apply a Function and Rename Variables with Sequential Names in a data set

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a new series of variables based on the exponential transform. Each variables name is sequential a1, a2, ... an. My first attempt looks like this:

```
data have;
 input a1 a2 a3 a4;
 datalines;
 1 3 4 5
 45 4 4 3
 45 4 7 8
 345 3 2 1
 3 4 3 1
 5 4 1 4;
run;

data want;
 set have;
  do i=1 to 4;  
   expa&i = exp(a&i);   
 end;
run;
```

It appears that my error is made in the do loop statement where I am renaming the variable with the indexer. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to RENAME the variables?  Transform the existing variables using `exp()` function? Or create new variables by transforming the original variables?  If the later do you want to keep the original variables or drop them?

Comment: I'm looking to transform them with a new names that make sense. So -expa1, expa2, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `ARRAY` statements.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array old a1-a4 ;
  array new expa1-expa4 ;
  do i=1 to dim(old);  
    new(i) = exp(old(i));   
  end;
  drop i ;
run;
```